# jQuery DatePicker + TimePicker in Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, joomla3.3

Has anybody used a time picker in this link?

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

I have already followed the steps in the link, I added the add-on.js file to my component and the css file inside, but when i change this code

```
var x = jQuery(this).attr("size");                  
jQuery(this).datepicker({ minDate:"0"-120, maxDate: "0"-x,dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd" });
```

to this :

```
var x = jQuery(this).attr("size");                  
jQuery(this).datetimepicker({ minDate:"0"-120, maxDate: "0"-x,dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd" });
```

nothing happens. I just want to add a timepicker to the datepicker I used from JqueryUI. Does joomla have something to do with this?

I used this code to load the javascript files from the link that I provided above :

```
$doc->addScript(JUri::base().'/components/com_subscription/media/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js');

$doc->addStyleSheet(JUri::base().'/components/com_subscription/media/css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css');
```

here is a screenshot of the error when the page loads:

[image]

I was confused because from the link that I am following, it just used the .datetimepicker then it works, but when I use mine, it's not functioning.

The screenshot also displays $.ui is undefined, but that code came from the js file which was from the link I am following.

Comment: have you fullfilled all the requiremnts in your Page ?

Comment: yes, I downloaded the addon, the CSS, and already added them in the page using addscript.

Comment: Not only that u also require jQuery,jQueryUI (with datepicker and slider wigits),Timepicker widjets

Comment: where exactly is the link for timepicker widget?

Comment: In the link which you have attached you have a thing called Github just explore it you will get some ideas. "https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon"